# How to change main slider image when carousel arrow is been clicked?

Tags: jquery, html, css, dom, flexslider

I have a main div containing big image. And have small thumbnail below that. 
I'm writing this:

```
> <script type="text/javascript">
>                 $(document).ready(function(){
>                   $('#carousel').flexslider({
>                     animation: "slide",
>                     controlNav: false,
>                     animationLoop: false,
>                     slideshow: false,
>                     itemWidth: 150,
>                     itemMargin: 5,
>                     asNavFor: '#slider'
>                   });
> 
>                   $('#slider').flexslider({
>                     animation: "slide",
>                     controlNav: false,
>                     animationLoop: false,
>                     slideshow: false,
>                     sync: "#carousel",
>                     start: function(slider){
>                       $('body').removeClass('loading');
>                     }
>                   });
> 
>                 });
>             </script>
```

Now when I click on the arrow(both previous and next) of the main big image, the thumbnail images move.
Now I want to do the same thing when thumbnail slider's arrow(both previous and next) is being clicked and the main big image gets changed.
Anybody?

you might want to check this http://flexslider.woothemes.com/thumbnail-slider.html
here clicking on thumbnail arrow doesn't change the main big image.
I want to achieve that.

Comment: create a jsfiddle, http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: you might want to check this http://flexslider.woothemes.com/thumbnail-slider.html
here clicking on thumbnail arrow doesn't change the main big image.
I want to achieve that.

Comment: You want to switch to next tumbnail image (when clicked previous or next button) instead of whole set being shifted , right ?

Comment: When the arrow of a thumbnail image is clicked I want to change the above big image, the main image.

Answer (score 0):

This is simple. 
Bind the click on the arrow to make a click on next sibling slide.

Caution: If slide is not visible do the original arrow thing. :) It may do it it self but not necessary.

It works :) - tested on site with example - just simply do this. :)

```
$('.flex-next').on('click', function(e){ e.preventDefault(); $('.flex-active-slide').next('li').click();
```

Comment: typical way to bypass the slider api ;)

Comment: I would play with events but don't know if the.big.lebowski has got the skills. :)
In my career i did played with source code of few plugins including three.js, mcustomscrollbar... don't remember. :)
And another example of my love to JS code: :D  http://gabrielecirulli.github.io/2048/ Current best is mine - 168152 - i did change some things in console .

Comment: Brilliant stuff, few times it result in unknown issues, but as you said need to be an experty in jQuery :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.flex-next').on('click', function(e){ e.preventDefault();$('#slider').flexslider('next') });
$('.flex-prev').on('click', function(e){ e.preventDefault();$('#slider').flexslider('previous') });
```

Hi guys I got myself fixed. Its pretty simple, didn't get earlier, was stupid.